# PHP Login Code not Setting Permanent Cookie (Through Browser Close)

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm using a PHP/MySQL Login Code, and I want it to store the cookie permanently (through browser closes), however it doesn't work. It logs in fine, and will remember up to a browser close, but forgets it afterwards. How can I fix this?

*This is all the important code I think;*

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined

session_name('tzLogin');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(1000000*7*24*60*60);

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['tzRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the tzRemember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}

if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors

    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
            // We create the tzRemember cookie
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
        $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
        // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: nowloggedin.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the expire time for the cookie:

```
setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe'], time()+3600);
```

That will make it last for one hour for example. If you don't set a time, it'll expire when the session is ended.

I've just noticed that you are setting the lifetime with session_set_cookie_params - as others have said, you're setting that way too far into the future.

Comment: Just a reminder: a pretty way of better "calculating" the desired time difference is with the help of `strtotime("+1 day")` instead of doing these `time()*60*60*24` monstrosities. [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Answer (score 1):

It's best to stay below this year...

```
2038
```

Otherwise there will be issues and your browser will not store it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the cookie as:

```
session_set_cookie_params(1000000*7*24*60*60);
```

Which sets the cookie to expire in 1000000*7*24*60*60 = 7*1000000/365 =  19000+ years. As far as I know, UNIX timestamp is not set for that long duration.